# Destroy session except one variable in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables

In symfony at the time of logout I want to destroy all my session variables except one. I want keep locale in session as it is after destroying session. Here is the code

```
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('locale', $locale);
    $session->invalidate(1);
```

Here I want to remove whole session except the "locale" variable.
Any suggestions how I can implement this?

Comment: you have to remove one by one

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the session and after that set the locale.

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->clear();
$session->set('locale', $locale);
```